# BluetoothGattServer characteristic: can't enable BluetoothGattCharacteristic notification

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth

I'm trying to create a peripheral Bluetooth LE with my Android device. I'd also like to send characteristic with it.

So I made these steps:

1- Create a BluetoothGattCharacteristic with NOTIFY property and READ permission.

2- Add a String value encoded in bytes

3- Create a BluetoothGattService and add the characteristic to this service

4- Create a BluetoothGattServer and added service to the server

5- Start BluetoothLeAdvertiser

Here is the code:

```
private void advertise() {

    String toBeSent = "I'm an Android" + "EOM";
    BluetoothGattCharacteristic ccc = new BluetoothGattCharacteristic(
            UUID.fromString(getString(R.string.ble_uuid)),
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_NOTIFY,
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_READ
    );

    BluetoothGattService service = new BluetoothGattService(UUID.fromString(getString(R.string.ble_uuid)), BluetoothGattService.SERVICE_TYPE_PRIMARY);
    byte[] bytes = toBeSent.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    ccc.setValue(bytes);

BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = new BluetoothGattDescriptor(UUID.fromString(getString(R.string.ble_uuid)), BluetoothGattDescriptor.PERMISSION_READ);
    descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
    ccc.addDescriptor(descriptor);

    service.addCharacteristic(ccc);

    BluetoothManager manager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService (Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);

    BluetoothGattServer server = manager.openGattServer(this, new BluetoothGattServerCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothDevice device, int status, int newState) {
            super.onConnectionStateChange(device, status, newState);
            Log.i("onConnectionStateChange", "Status: " + status);
            switch (newState) {
                case BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED:
                    Log.i("gattCallback", "STATE_CONNECTED");
                    break;
                case BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED:
                    Log.e("gattCallback", "STATE_DISCONNECTED");
                    found = false;
                    break;
                default:
                    Log.e("gattCallback", "STATE_OTHER");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceAdded(int status, BluetoothGattService service) {
            super.onServiceAdded(status, service);
        }

        @Override
        public void onExecuteWrite(BluetoothDevice device, int requestId, boolean execute) {
            super.onExecuteWrite(device, requestId, execute);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNotificationSent(BluetoothDevice device, int status) {
            super.onNotificationSent(device, status);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicWriteRequest(BluetoothDevice device, int requestId, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, boolean preparedWrite, boolean responseNeeded, int offset, byte[] value) {
            super.onCharacteristicWriteRequest(device, requestId, characteristic, preparedWrite, responseNeeded, offset, value);
        }
    });
    server.addService(service);

    BluetoothLeAdvertiser advertiser = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getBluetoothLeAdvertiser();

        AdvertiseSettings settings = new AdvertiseSettings.Builder()
                .setAdvertiseMode( AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_MODE_LOW_LATENCY )
                .setTxPowerLevel( AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_TX_POWER_HIGH )
                .setConnectable(true)
                .build();

        ParcelUuid pUuid = new ParcelUuid( UUID.fromString( getString( R.string.ble_uuid ) ) );

        AdvertiseData data = new AdvertiseData.Builder().setIncludeDeviceName(false).addServiceUuid( pUuid )
                .build();

        AdvertiseCallback advertisingCallback = new AdvertiseCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onStartSuccess(AdvertiseSettings settingsInEffect) {
                super.onStartSuccess(settingsInEffect);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartFailure(int errorCode) {
                super.onStartFailure(errorCode);
            }
        };

        advertiser.startAdvertising( settings, data, advertisingCallback );
}
```

I'm trying to read characteristics from this server on an iOS device in a BLE Central mode. I can discover and connect to Android peripheral, but I can't read the characteristic value, because the notification flag (or bit) seems to not be listened.
In other words the iOS device can see the characteristic, but method to enable characteristic notification seems not working.

```
[peripheral setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:characteristic];
```

The iOS central finds the characteristic, but doesn't call notification delegate because can't find NOTIFY property.

I've tried to connect this iOS central with an iOS peripheral with characteristic's NOTIFY property enabled and all is working well, so my first thought is that I'm missing something in Android. Is Android part completely correct?

For more clarity here are the characteristic on that starts from Android and arrives to iOS:

[Android characteristic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JkKi.png)

[iOS characteristic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjoYj.png)

Comment: you should add the descriptor of the character.

Comment: refer http://blog.csdn.net/sinat_19628093/article/details/51789617

Comment: @Guo Xingmin
How should I add a descriptor?

I've used 
`BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = new BluetoothGattDescriptor(UUID.fromString(getString(R.string.ble_uuid)), BluetoothGattDescriptor.PERMISSION_WRITE | BluetoothGattDescriptor.PERMISSION_READ);
        descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
ccc.addDescriptor(descriptor);`


Nothing changed.
In your code I can't see any descriptor addiction.

Comment: will you post the btsnoop log or adb log.

Comment: I've posted my 2 characteristics: one which starts from Android and one which comes to iOS. ADB says nothing about. Only connection status. I cannot snoop BT right now. I think there is something missing in Android that I don't know with characteristic write.

Comment: I could not find the descriptor settings on your code?

Comment: I'm sorry...just edited